# compare multiple algorithms in the same dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dataset, multiple-comparisons

I want to do a comparison between multiple algorithms when they applied to the same dataset. For example, I have a set of texts in Arabic and another version translated to English. I did a sentiment analysis by using different sentiment tools and by using annotators. So, I want to find a suitable statistical test can help me to illustrate the difference.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking for. When you say "I want to find a suitable statistical test can help me to illustrate the difference", what difference do you mean? The difference in the performance of the algorithm, or the difference in the results between the two data sets?

Comment: I want to examine if there is any difference in the result of different algorithms.

Comment: sentiment analysis is not mainstream. Show data, method, and references if you want to get a nibble for an answer.

Comment: Please tell us about the results that are output by the sentiment tools. Are they scores? Are they continuous? Are they categorical? 

Also, what type of difference in the scores are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First apply k-fold cross-validation (e.g., k = 10). Afterwards apply a paired T-test.

Have a look on Peter Flach's great book "Machine Learning: The Art and Science of Algorithms that Make Sense of Data". There is also a online-version of if, look up page 529:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ya4ynGkqSxdXRoVmJFNmJEQTQ/edit

Comment: But my data set is not normally distributed. So, I cannot apply t-test